# Continuity up to the boundary of a continuous function for which the limit in the normal direction exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

If I have a function $f(x, t)$ defined in the half-space ($x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0$) that is there continuous and I know that for any fixed $x_0$, $f(x_0, t) \rightarrow f(x_0, 0)$ when $t \rightarrow 0^+$, can I conclude that the function is continuous up to the boundary ($x \in \mathbb{R}, t \ge 0$)?

I am stuck at this point (fixing $\varepsilon > 0)$:
$$
|f(x, t) - f(x_0, 0)| \le |f(x, t) - f(x_0, t)| + |f(x_0, t) - f(x_0, 0)| \le |f(x, t) - f(x_0, t)| + \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$

The second term is due to the limit existing (provided $t \le t_0(\varepsilon)$), but I do not know how to handle the first term. I only know that for any fixed $t > 0$ there is a $\delta(\varepsilon, t)$ such that if $|x - x_0| < \delta$ the first term is less than $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, but I need to drop the dependency on $t$ to really have continuity.